# Separar componentes Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Dentro de um alertDialog eu criei uma column com os checkbox e depois uma Row com dois FlatButton, porém eles ficam lado a lado e eu preciso que os mesmos fiquem abaixo dos checkbox.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código**

```
AlertDialog(
...
actions: <Widget>[
    Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Checkbox(
                value: false,
              ),
              Text("Teste 123"),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Checkbox(
                value: false,
              ),
              Text("Teste 0321"),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text(
                  AppLocalizations.of(context).cancel.toUpperCase(),
                ),
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text(
                  AppLocalizations.of(context).send.toUpperCase(),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
```

Eu consegui obter o resultado esperado apenas envolvendo o column com um container e elevando seu width ao maximo da tela, mas isso sai do padrão das outras dialogs do app e faz com que ela fique errada dependendo do dispositivo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Onde está o código do resto do alertDialog? O que você vai fazer com o Checkbox? Acredito que a ideia dessa propriedade ```Actions``` é apenas para os botões que ficam no inferior da tela. Algum motivo para você não colocar os Checkbox's dentro do ```content```?

Comment: Isso que o Flutter faz está correto... Você está colocando um `Container` com os checkbox's dentro da `Actions` (Que é para Botões de ações), o certo é mover esses checkbox's para dentro do corpo do dialog e deixá-los alinhado ao _Bottom_.

Comment: Realmente mano, eu achei que nao precisava colocar todo o código visto que todos meus elementos estavam no actions. Eu tentei fazer o que tu disse sobre colocar os componentes no content e deu super certo aqui, se quiser pode comentar a resposta que eu coloco como correto. Obrigado !!

Comment: Sim @MatheusRibeiro, mas é errando que se aprende, foi minha primeira experimentar com esse componente, mas também acredito que foi falta de atenção minha na hora de ler a documentação. De qualquer forma obrigado!!

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente, os widgets que vão compor seu `AlertDialog` devem estar no atributo `content`

Os teus `FlatButton` devem estar fora dessa Row que você colocou, devem estar cada um solto dentro do atributo `actions`

Fiz esse script porém não tive como testar no momento:

```
AlertDialog(
      title: Text("Simples Alerta"),
      content: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Checkbox(
                value: false,
                onChanged: alterarCheck,
              ),
              Text("Teste 123"),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Checkbox(
                value: false,
                onChanged: alterarCheck,
              ),
              Text("Teste 0321"),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      actions: [
        FlatButton(
          child: Text(
            AppLocalizations.of(context).cancel.toUpperCase(),
          ),
          onPressed: ()=>Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        ),
        FlatButton(
          child: Text(
            AppLocalizations.of(context).send.toUpperCase(),
          ),
          onPressed: ()=>Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Explicação:

No `AlertDialog` todo o corpo do dialog deve estar dentro de algum widget no atributo `content`, nesse caso o `Column`.
Os botões devem estar soltos dentro do atributo `action`